# Laravel blade, cannot access relationship in blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have simple implementation of oneToMany, Category -> Features, but cannot access features from blade template.

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\StoreVenueRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Feature;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\City;
use App\Models\Venue;

class VenueController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Category $category)
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        $cities = City::all();

        // dd($category->features);

        return view('frontend.venues.create', [
            'category' => $category,
            'categories' => $categories,
            'cities' => $cities,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Template (`create.blade.php`):

```
<div class="checkboxes in-row amenities_checkbox">
    {{ dd($category->features) }}
    <ul>
        @foreach ($category->features as $feature)
            <li>
                <input id="{{ $feature->code }}" value="{{ $feature->id }}" type="checkbox" name="features_bool[]">
                <label for="{{ $feature->code }}">{{ $feature->name_bg }}</label>
            </li>
        @endforeach

    </ul>
</div>
```

Category model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function venues()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Venue::class);
    }

    public function features()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Feature::class);
    }
}
```

Feature model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Feature extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Commented row in the controller `dd($category->features);` returns:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1411 ▼
  #items: array:8 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Feature {#1434 ▶}
    1 => App\Models\Feature {#1429 ▶}
    2 => App\Models\Feature {#1452 ▶}
    3 => App\Models\Feature {#1407 ▶}
    4 => App\Models\Feature {#1456 ▶}
    5 => App\Models\Feature {#1458 ▶}
    6 => App\Models\Feature {#1439 ▶}
    7 => App\Models\Feature {#1254 ▶}
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

Same row in the blade file `{{ dd($category->features) }}` returns empty array:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1447 ▼
  #items: []
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

I checked most of the questions with similar problems, but without any success. I have needed relationships `hasMany` and `belongsTo`.

Route definition:

```
// Venues
Route::get('/venues/create/{category}', [VenueController::class, 'create'])->name('venues.create');
```

Url:

```
http://localhost:8000/venues/create/1
```

How I access it:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
 <li><a href="{{ route('venues.create', ['category' => $category]) }}">{{ $category->name_en }}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Well when I read my question, I found something unusual Collection id in controller is 1411, and in blade file it's 1447, is that matters ?

Comment: it does not matter

Comment: Sounds like something is cached, because this should work fine; try `php artisan optimize:clear`. As a general rule you should do eager loading though, so `$categories = Category::with('features')->get();`

Comment: What does the route definition look like, and the URL you are using to access the page?

Comment: @miken32 It's edit.

Answer (score 0):

---

Well, my guess is when you try to load `features` server-side, Laravel can lazy query your relation and include it to your model, but if you do the same directly on blade, it's too late so your collection remains empty.

If you need to load your relation punctually, you can get a fresh instance of your model and load relations:

```
public function create(Category $category)
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $cities = City::all();

    // dd($category->features);

    return view('frontend.venues.create', [
        'category' => $category->fresh(['features']),
        'categories' => $categories,
        'cities' => $cities,
    ]);
}
```

but if you need thoses relations every time the model is loaded, then you can overwrite the property `$with` in your model class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The relations to eager load on every query.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['features'];

    public function venues()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Venue::class);
    }

    public function features()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Feature::class);
    }
}
```

---

Comment: there is no 'too late' ... accessing the dynamic property will load the relationship if it isn't already loaded it has no awareness of context

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried both options, together and separately, without any success.

Comment: also you don't need to get a fresh instance, you can just lazy eager load relationships with `load` ...`$category->load('features')`